# pycharm & jupyter not working

Tags: pycharm, jupyter

I am trying to run jupytor notebook on pycharm , i found some post suggesting to install notebook 4.3 but it didn't work.

after clicking on cancel after

> http://localhost:8888/?token=

I clicked on

> Cannot connect to Jupyter Notebook. Run Jupyter Notebook

## #

I get this massage:
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
[I 12:30:03.550 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[C 12:30:03.550 NotebookApp] ERROR: the notebook server could not be started because no available port could be found.

## #

what to do? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there! Just change the port number from the default 8888 to 8881 (if it is free) by going to the Run menu and select "edit configuration" and change port 8888 to any other free port. Apply the changes and restart Pycharm.

Also, you may search using the command line for those apps that are sitting on port 8888 and end their processes or just to check if the port is free or not.This vary from an OS to another. In windows you may refer to https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/10/how-to-check-which-application-is-using-which-port/